# Can't get application properties from async method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

```
@Service
public Class SomeService {

    private SomeServiceAsync someServiceAsync = new SomeServiceAsync();

    ...

    public String DoAThing() {
        CompletableFurute<String> future = someServiceAsync.GetAString();
        return future.get();
    }
}

@Service
@EnableAsync
public Class SomeServiceAsync {

    @Value("${someProp1}")
    private String someProp1;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    ...

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> GetAString() {
        System.out.println(someProp1); // returns null
        String someProp2 env.getProperty("someProp2"); // throws null pointer exception

        return CompletableFurute.completedFuture("blablabla");
    }
}
```

My problem is simply that I cannot access my application properties after making some of my methods run asynchronously. Nothing is failing before I try to execute the method and either get a null from @Value or env is null.

The method worked before making it async, and the async version works fine when I am not accessing the application properties.

Comment: Did you change folder structure after that?? property file/yaml file in proper place??

Comment: It's in the same place and my other classes can still get the properties.

Comment: @Value("${someProp1}")
    private String someProp1;
Are you able to acces the same property from other classes??

Comment: The `new SomeServiceAsync()` may be the problem?  If a bean is constructed directly, instead of being @Autowired, Spring will be unable to 'advise' the @Async method.

Comment: @df778899 shoot, that was all it was. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll select it as soon as the site will let me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was the `new SomeServiceAsync()`, instead of an `@Autowired`.

Made the same mistake myself many times.